# variables not passing to view in laravel from controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Variables not passing to views in laravel project from the controller. getting Undefined variable: title error.

```
function index()
{

    $data = array(
        'title' => 'Font Awesome & Material Design Icons',
        'description' => 'Create your project with Font Awesome & Material Design Icons',
        'seo_keywords' => 'Create your project with Font Awesome & Material Design Icons',
        'data' => DB::table('fontawesomeicons')->orderBy('id', 'asc')->paginate(50),
    );   

    // $data = DB::table('fontawesomeicons')->orderBy('id', 'asc')->paginate(50);
    return view('pagination', compact('data'));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[The `compact` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) will create an array with `data` as the only key and the array as its value. This is not what you should do, you need an array that directly contains the variables you need in your view.

So you can just pass the data array as the second attribute for the `view()` function.

```
return view('pagination', $data);
```

---

Or if you really want to send the entire `$data` array as a whole variable, you have to use the array indexes in your blade views:

```
{{ $data['title'] }}
```

Comment: I need to do it with compact because i rendering to some other blade file in pagination blade

Comment: I added an example that you can use if you want to send the entire `$data` array to your view.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
return view('pagination')->with(compact('data'));
```

Or try

```
$title = 'Font Awesome & Material Design Icons';
$description = 'Create your project with Font Awesome & Material Design Icons';
$seo_keywords = 'Create your project with Font Awesome & Material Design Icons';
$data = DB::table('fontawesomeicons')->orderBy('id', 'asc')->paginate(50);

return view('pagination',compac(['title','description','seo_keywords','data']));
```

Answer (score 0):

`compact('data')` returns array like this: `['data' => $data]`

So `return view('pagination', compact('data'));` code is equivalent to this:

```
return view('pagination', ['data' => $data]);
```

And you have access to controller variable like this: `$data['title']` , `$data['description']` ...
You shold pass data in view instead of `compact('data')`:

```
return view('pagination', $data);
```

Or you can use

```
return view('pagination', compact('data')['data']);
```

But this doesn't makes sense

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this:

```
function index()
{

    $data['data'] = array(
        'title' => 'Font Awesome & Material Design Icons',
        'description' => 'Create your project with Font Awesome & Material Design Icons',
        'seo_keywords' => 'Create your project with Font Awesome & Material Design Icons',
        'data' => DB::table('fontawesomeicons')->orderBy('id', 'asc')->paginate(50),
    );   

    // $data = DB::table('fontawesomeicons')->orderBy('id', 'asc')->paginate(50);
    return view('pagination', $data);
}
```